# Hours spent in something takes a singular or plural verb?

Tags: verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

For example ''*Hours spent in online multiplayer gaming per week*'' is it takes *are* or *is*?

Comment: Hello, Gamze. Could you please expand this to a sentence (you can use '**is/are**' for the verbform you are asking about). It might be that you have more than one sentence in mind, one perhaps involving a numeral (' ... 7 hours spent ...'). This could make a difference.

Comment: Hello, of course, I can. I am talking about a graph which shows hours spent in games per week. In this sentence, I was saying that hours spent in games per week is/are increased. I hope I could make it clear ^^. Thank you by the way ^^.

Comment: I'd go with 'time' ... 'has', or 'number of hours' ... 'has'. It's a tricky area. 'Ten hours is a long time to spend on one essay' but 'Many hours have been wasted on trying to source bandages from foreing suppliers'.

Comment: Why not just say _hours spent in games per week increased_? There's no need for a passive because there's no agent necessary. The verb is intransitive to start with. And, happily, you can avoid using _be_, the only verb in the language that marks the singular and plural in the past.

Comment: Please provide a sentence with a blank (___) into which *is* or *are* would be placed. In the current sentence in the question, neither makes sense. It's not clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, thank you all soo much ^^

Comment: @JasonBassford okay, ''Hours spent in online multiplayer gaming per week (      ) increasing gradually.''  into which is or are should be placed?

Comment: @GamzeDeniz In that example sentence, it should be plural (*are*).